# How to execute multiple scripts with Salt cmd.script?

Tags: salt-stack

I'm trying to apply salt state that consist of multiple scripts. But some reason only script4 is running.

Here's my state file.

```
#!jinja|yaml|gpg

Distro_Specific_Scripts:
  cmd.script:
    - name: Run Scripts.sh
  {% if grains['os_family'] == 'RedHat' %}
    - source: salt://scripts/files/scripts/script_for_redhat.sh
  {% elif grains['os_family'] == 'Debian' %}
    - source: salt://scripts/files/scripts/script_for_ubuntu.sh
  {% endif %}
    - source: salt://scripts/files/scripts/script2.sh
    - source: salt://scripts/files/scripts/script3.sh
    - source: salt://scripts/files/scripts/script4.sh
```

Would you share your experience about running multiple scripts? or Would you tell me where i went wrong.

Comment: You can't repeat arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to write this.

OPTION 1:

This will be the simplest method. If you have scripts corresponding to the `grains['os_family']`, i.e.

- `script_for_debian.sh` for Debian
- `script_for_ubuntu.sh` for Ubuntu
- `script_for_redhat.sh` for RedHat

```yaml
run_my_scripts:
  cmd.script:
    - names:
        - salt://scripts/files/scripts/script_for_{{ grains['os_family'] | lower }}.sh
        - salt://scripts/files/scripts/script2.sh
        - salt://scripts/files/scripts/script3.sh
        - salt://scripts/files/scripts/script4.sh
```

OPTION 2:

If not, then we can set the script name conditionally and outside the state declaration:

```
{% set os_specific_script = salt['grains.filter_by']({
  'Debian': 'script_for_ubuntu.sh',
  'RedHat': 'script_for_redhat.sh'
}) %}

run_my_scripts:
  cmd.script:
    - names:
        - salt://scripts/files/scripts/{{ os_specific_script }}
        - salt://scripts/files/scripts/script2.sh
        - salt://scripts/files/scripts/script3.sh
        - salt://scripts/files/scripts/script4.sh
```

If you have control over the name of scripts, OPTION 1 will be a better choice.

Comment: [`grains.filter_by`](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.grains.html#salt.modules.grains.filter_by) is designed for exactly this

Comment: Agreed! Thanks for the pointer, it looks cleaner. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found a way to achieve my goal. But if there's a smartest way to do it any help would be appreciated :)

```
#!jinja|yaml|gpg

Distro_Specific_Scripts:
  cmd.script:
    - name: Distro Specific Scripts
  {% if grains['os_family'] == 'RedHat' %}
    - source: salt://scripts/files/scripts/script_for_redhat.sh
  {% elif grains['os_family'] == 'Debian' %}
    - source: salt://scripts/files/scripts/script_for_debian.sh
  {% endif %}
script2:
  cmd.script:
    - name: script2.sh
    - source: salt://scripts/files/scripts/script2.sh
script3:
  cmd.script:
    - name: script3
    - source: salt://scripts/files/scripts/script2.sh
script4:
  cmd.script:
    - name: script4.sh
    - source: salt://scripts/files/scripts/script2.sh
```

Comment: You don't need to repeat the `name`.